# result should be obtained as comma separated

Tags: foreach, codeigniter-3, implode

My code for the slide looks like this in the static form.

```
<div id="demo-1" data-zs-src='["<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/s1.jpg", "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/sd1.jpg", "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/slide7.jpg", "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/sd3.jpg"]' data-zs-overlay="dots">
<div class="demo-inner-content">
  <h1><span>Tasty</span> & <span>Healthy</span></h1>
  <p>For those who have taste for life.</p>
</div>
```

and when i change it into dynamic i changed my code like this

```
<?php foreach($slide1 as $ss){?>
```

```
data-zs-src='["<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $ss->image;?>" ]' alt=""
data-zs-overlay="dots">


<div class="demo-inner-content">
  <h1><span>Tasty</span> & <span>Healthy</span></h1>
  <p>For those who have taste for life.</p>
</div>
```

My problem is the slide will work only when comma is added after each image for that i thought to add implode function but its not working properly and my code with implode looks like this

```
 <div id="demo-1"  data-zs-src='[<?php foreach( $slides as $slide ){ $images="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $slide->image;?>";
?>"<?php echo implode(',',$images);?>"<?php }?>]' 
data-zs-overlay="dots">



<div class="demo-inner-content">
  <h1><span>Tasty</span> & <span>Healthy</span></h1>
  <p>For those who have taste for life.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: please help me solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have to think about what it is you are trying to achieve here...

You seem to be trying to perform an implode on each string inside the foreach loop... Apart from the errors that would have been generated, it doesn't  make sense to perform that in each loop. Its something you do after you have created the array entries... Implode works on arrays, not strings. It generates a string from an array.

Basically you are wanting to take an array of objects and want to convert those into a comma delimited string.

I'm not sure why you insist of putting ALL the code inside the HTML code where you want it to appear... I'd separate it out like this...

```
<?php foreach ($slides as $slide) {
    $images[] = base_url('uploads/') . $slide->image;
} ?>

<div id="demo-1" data-zs-src='["
    <?= implode(',', $images); ?>
        "]'
     data-zs-overlay="dots">
    <div class="demo-inner-content">
        <h1><span>Tasty</span> & <span>Healthy</span></h1>
        <p>For those who have taste for life.</p>
    </div>
```

Step 1: Create your Array of images

```
<?php foreach ($slides as $slide) {
    $images[] = base_url('uploads/') . $slide->image;
} ?>
```

This can be done in your controller or in a helper but in your view is just as good. Depends on how you like to structure your code.

Step 2: Put the resulting string where you want it.

```
<div id="demo-1" data-zs-src='["
    <?= implode(',', $images); ?>
        "]'
     data-zs-overlay="dots">
    <div class="demo-inner-content">
        <h1><span>Tasty</span> & <span>Healthy</span></h1>
        <p>For those who have taste for life.</p>
    </div>
```

You can refactor this even more but I have taken the first step in refactoring it so it hopefully makes sense to you.

NOTE: I have used `<?=` instead of `<?php echo` ( available since **PHP 5.4.0**) so if you are using something older than 5.4.0 stick with `<?php echo`.